# Show the Oracle Datetime format in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, datetime

So, I'm new to my company and I have the code that developped by our past developer and I have to modify a bit. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> PAYMENT LIST </title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function urlorder(a)
{
    var urlorder="order.php?on="+a;
    var prmpt=window.open(urlorder,"test","left=200,top=150,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=640,height=480");
}
function printorder(a,b)
{


var urlorder="printorder.php?on="+a+"&nu=2&tgl="+b;
    //var prmpt=window.open(urlorder,"test","left=200,top=150,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=640,height=480");
    window.location = urlorder;
    //alert (urlorder);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?
//include "ceksession.php";
include 'connect.php';

//ambil tgl val
$q = "select tgl_val from para_info_kntr";
$s = OCIParse($c,$q);
OCIBindByName($s,":bind1",$ltid);
OCIExecute($s,OCI_DEFAULT);
while (OCIFetch($s))
{   
    $tgl=ociresult($s,"TGL_VAL");
    echo $tgl."<br>";
}
$tgl= date('d-m-Y', strtotime($tgl));
$tgl= date('d-m-Y');
//echo $tgl."<br>";

$tgl = $_GET["tgl"];

echo "<div align=\"right\">";
echo "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"window.location='month.php'\") value=\"HOME\">";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div align=\"center\">";
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"44\">";
echo "<div align=\"center\">PAYMENT LIST</div>";
echo "</td></tr>";

$q = "Select * from payment_final where bt_number=".$bt_number." and to_char(tgl_val,'DD-MM-YYYY')='".$tgl."' order by bill_no";
//echo $q;
$s2=OCIParse($c_slave,$q);
OCIBindByName($s2,":bind1",$ordernumber);
OCIExecute($s2,OCI_DEFAULT);

echo "<tr><td>";
echo "PAYMENT_NUMBER";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "TABLE_ID";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "ORDER_NUMBER";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "TGL_VAL";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "PAY_DATE";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "AMOUNT";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "DISCOUNT_AMOUNT";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "SERVICES";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "TAX";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "TOTAL_AMOUNT";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "BILL_NO";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "PRINT";
echo "</td></tr>";


while (OCIFetch($s2))
{
    $V_GUEST_FOLIO        = oci_result($s2,'GUEST_FOLIO');
    $V_PAYMENT_NUMBER     = oci_result($s2,'PAYMENT_NUMBER');
    $V_TABLE_ID           = oci_result($s2,'TABLE_ID');
    $V_ORDER_NUMBER       = oci_result($s2,'ORDER_NUMBER');
    $V_TGL_VAL            = oci_result($s2,'TGL_VAL');
    $V_PAY_DATE           = oci_result($s2,'PAY_DATE');
    $V_AMOUNT             = oci_result($s2,'AMOUNT');
    $V_DISCOUNT_MK        = oci_result($s2,'DISCOUNT_MK');
    $V_DISCOUNT_MN        = oci_result($s2,'DISCOUNT_MN');
    $V_DISCOUNT_KM        = oci_result($s2,'DISCOUNT_KM');
    $V_DISCOUNT_SN        = oci_result($s2,'DISCOUNT_SN');
    $V_DISCOUNT_EA        = oci_result($s2,'DISCOUNT_EA');
    $V_DISCOUNT_EB        = oci_result($s2,'DISCOUNT_EB');
    $V_DISCOUNT_AMOUNT    = oci_result($s2,'DISCOUNT_AMOUNT');
    $V_SERVICES           = oci_result($s2,'SERVICES');
    $V_TAX                = oci_result($s2,'TAX');
    $V_TOTAL_AMOUNT       = oci_result($s2,'TOTAL_AMOUNT');
    $V_CASH_PAID          = oci_result($s2,'CASH_PAID');
    $V_CASHIER_NUMBER     = oci_result($s2,'CASHIER_NUMBER');
    $V_WAITER_NUMBER      = oci_result($s2,'WAITER_NUMBER');
    $V_CUSTOMER_NUMBER    = oci_result($s2,'CUSTOMER_NUMBER');
    $V_PRINT_DATE         = oci_result($s2,'PRINT_DATE');
    $V_DP                 = oci_result($s2,'DP');
    $V_CARD_PAID1         = oci_result($s2,'CARD_PAID1');
    $V_CARD_PAID2         = oci_result($s2,'CARD_PAID2');
    $V_CARD_TYPE1         = oci_result($s2,'CARD_TYPE1');
    $V_CARD_NUMBER1       = oci_result($s2,'CARD_NUMBER1');
    $V_CARD_NAME_HOLDER1  = oci_result($s2,'CARD_NAME_HOLDER1');
    $V_CARD_TYPE2         = oci_result($s2,'CARD_TYPE2');
    $V_CARD_NUMBER2       = oci_result($s2,'CARD_NUMBER2');
    $V_CARD_NAME_HOLDER2  = oci_result($s2,'CARD_NAME_HOLDER2');
    $V_PAYMENT_METHOD     = oci_result($s2,'PAYMENT_METHOD');
    $V_AR_AMOUNT          = oci_result($s2,'AR_AMOUNT');
    $V_BT_NUMBER          = oci_result($s2,'BT_NUMBER');
    $V_FLAG_CETAK         = oci_result($s2,'FLAG_CETAK');
    $V_REC_ID             = oci_result($s2,'REC_ID');
    $V_FLAG_CTR           = oci_result($s2,'FLAG_CTR');
    $V_CHECK_NO           = oci_result($s2,'CHECK_NO');
    $V_VOUCHER            = oci_result($s2,'VOUCHER');
    $V_VOUCHER_NO         = oci_result($s2,'VOUCHER_NO');
    $V_CPL_AMOUNT         = oci_result($s2,'CPL_AMOUNT');
    $V_BILL_NO            = oci_result($s2,'BILL_NO');
    $V_AR_NAME            = oci_result($s2,'AR_NAME');
    $V_ENT_AMOUNT         = oci_result($s2,'ENT_AMOUNT');

    echo "</td><td>";
    /*
    <input type=\"button\" value=\"".$V_PAYMENT_NUMBER."\" onclick=\"urlorder(".$V_ORDER_NUMBER.")\")\" style=\"height: 25px; width: 70px;\">
    */
    echo "<a href=\"order.php?on=".$V_ORDER_NUMBER."\">";
    echo $V_PAYMENT_NUMBER;
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_TABLE_ID;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_ORDER_NUMBER;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_TGL_VAL;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_PAY_DATE;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_AMOUNT;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_DISCOUNT_AMOUNT;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_SERVICES;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_TAX;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_TOTAL_AMOUNT;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_BILL_NO;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"printorder(".$V_ORDER_NUMBER.",'".$tgl."')\") value=\"PRINT\">";
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is shown here:
[image: result]

in my DB Oracle, the field PAY_DATE's format like this : **02/01/2015 08:35:58**
But the result now it's just showing the Date only. What I'm trying to do is I want to show the date and time like this **02/01/2015 08:35:58** in the PAY_DATE column. Can you guys help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use to_char function in query to get the data from table.

e.g.

```
Select to_char("PAY_DATE","YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS") as "PAY_DATE" FROM table
```

Comment: put in your sql query where date field is selected.

Comment: $q = "Select * from payment_final where bt_number=".$bt_number." and to_char(tgl_val,'DD-MM-YYYY')='".$tgl."' order by bill_no";   --> become --> $q = "Select to_char("PAY_DATE","YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS") as "PAY_DATE"  from payment_final where bt_number=".$bt_number." and to_char(tgl_val,'DD-MM-YYYY')='".$tgl."' order by bill_no";    is that what you meant?

Comment: like. $q = "Select *, to_char(tgl_val,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') as tglval,to_char(pay_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') as paydate from payment_final.....

Comment: $q = "Select *, to_char(pay_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') as PAY_DATE from payment_final where bt_number=".$bt_number." and to_char(tgl_val,'DD-MM-YYYY')='".$tgl."' and to_char(tgl_val,'DD-MM-YYYY')='".$tgl."' order by bill_no";                      I try that and still not show up? am I missing something mate?

Comment: please not use to_char  in where condition.

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT TO_CHAR(PAY_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS') FROM "payment_final" where   TO_CHAR(PAY_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS') = = '02/01/2015 08:35:58'`

OR

`SELECT TO_CHAR(PAY_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS') FROM "payment_final" 
WHERE PAY_DATE = to_timestamp('02/01/2015 08:35:58','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`

see [Oracle Dates and Times](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html#date)   format

Comment: @liverpool put in your query

Comment: i put them here but the site doesnt show up --> $q = "Select TO_CHAR(PAY_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS') FROM from payment_final where bt_number=".$bt_number." and to_char(tgl_val,'DD-MM-YYYY')='".$tgl."' order by bill_no";

Comment: @Liverpool not in where statement

Comment: please give me example dude, i try put them in where statement but still give me error (not showing up))

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP `date` function for the respective as

```
$V_PAY_DATE; = date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime($V_PAY_DATE));
echo $V_PAY_DATE;
```

Comment: Hey, can you help me specify where I can put the code?

Comment: @Liverpool I have updated my answer you need to place this code after you are fetching from `database`

Comment: still not work out, can you help me the image please. bit confused about this

Comment: What you were getting within `$V_PAY_DATE`

Comment: my code right now ->> $V_PAY_DATE           = oci_result($s2,'PAY_DATE');   I already change becomne like this and error  --> $V_PAY_DATE   = date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime($V_PAY_DATE;));   --

Comment: Sorry my bad I have an error within `strtotime($V_PAY_DATE;))` which I have edited and check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74166/discussion-between-liverpool-and-narendra-sisodia).